# Lots of persistent requests to my web app from a private ip address

Tags: azure, security, networking, ip

I am more a C# dev than a network admin and I am not understanding what happened.

I have a website hosted on an Azure Web App and I started to get a lot of repetitive requests from IP address `172.16.5.1`, to a point that it affected the web server stability

The only way I found to fix the problem is to block this IP address, but I still have questions.

1) Is blocking the IP the best solution to the problem?

2) After googling, I found that this IP address is in the range of Private IP addresses. How can a private address reach my public web server?

3) Could it be another resource from my Azure subscription that could be making these requests?...I only have a web app configured so I don't know where these requests could come from internally

4) Can this be a DDoS attack?

Answer (score 0):

This IP Address is private range as you found it, but needs more information to answer your couriosity.

1. I could say that’s not the best solution, you need to find out which resources on your Azure that use that IP and see why it sends a request to Web App.
2. This is possible when your Web App connected to the Virtual Network, discuss with your Network Admin or System Architect.
3. I’m quiet sure that your Web App is connected to Virtual Network or could be another instance of your Web App requesting each other.
4. I’m not quiet sure that was an external DDoS attack.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be the default gateway for a subnet. Check the Networking blade to see if you are integrated with a VNet. I would expect that probes from something in the VNet (AppGW, Azure Firewall, NVA, etc.) would come from the instance IP of that resource and not the default gateway, but you really need to see the subnet range and know what's in there. If this is a WebApp that is integrated with a VNet via point-to-site VPN, then maybe this is something from the VNet Gateway, like Keep Alives. That might be apparent in a network trace. Blocking that IP could result in some other service marking the WebApp as unhealthy and not routing traffic to it. 
Lots of conjecture here, but like Rudy said, you're not getting an external DDOS attack from a private IP.